# How to associate the file extension of an Arduino sketch file (.ino file) as a C/C++ file for syntax highlighting?

Tags: arduino, kdevelop

I'd like to use KDevelop as my editor.  How do I tell KDevelop to treat the .ino files as C/C++ files so it does things like syntax highlights and "Jump to Declaration"?

Is there a place to associate file extensions?

Answer (score 2):

I take it, you can edit [Kate's syntax highlighting file for C++](https://cgit.kde.org/syntax-highlighting.git/tree/data/syntax/cpp.xml), and add .ino extension to `extensions` attribute of `<language>` entity. Let me know if that worked for you, so I'll upstream this.

And BTW, there is a [work-in-progress KDevelop plugin](https://cgit.kde.org/kdev-embedded.git/) for developing for embedded systems. You might find it interesting (if you aren't using it already).

Comment: "Jump to Declaration" will not work with by using Kate syntax highlighting files, though. You'll need a proper patch like https://phabricator.kde.org/D5072 in KDevelop to properly support .ino files.

Answer (score 0):

Open SystemSettings, go to 'Applications -> File Associations', search for 'x-c++src', and add '*.ino' to the list of filename patterns.

Alternatively, edit `/usr/share/mime/text/x-c++src.xml` manually, which has the same effect.